# jquery scrollto mousewheel issue

Tags: jquery, scrollto, mousewheel

I have really annoying problem with ScrollTo plugin.

The webpage is: http://webdizajntest.com/amphiro

As you can see, i have made some kind of vertical scrolling homepage with mousewheel triggering event to scroll to next and previous div.

It was all working perfect until i changed something (I have no idea what) and now it's only working when i mousewheel down! When I mousewheel up, it is still scrolling down.

Just to be clear, i need this kind of scrolling: http://www.beoplay.com/Products/BeoplayA8

The code that I use to accomplish this is:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {     

    var $current, flag = false; 

    jQuery(function() {          
        jQuery('body').mousewheel(function(event, delta) {
            if (flag) { return false; }
            $current = jQuery('div.current');

            console.log(delta);
            console.log($current);

            if (delta < 0) {
                $prev = $current.prev();

                if ($prev.length) {
                    flag = true;

                    /* Ako je prvi */
                    if($current.attr('id') == "home-first"){
                        $prev = jQuery("#top-home");
                    }

                    if($current.attr('id') == "top-home"){
                        $prev = $current;
                    }

                    if($current.attr('id') == "vision-technology"){
                        jQuery('body').scrollTo('#top-home', 1000, {
                            onAfter : function(){
                                flag = false;
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    else{
                        jQuery('body').scrollTo($prev, 1000, {
                            onAfter : function(){
                                flag = false;
                            }
                        });
                    }

                    $current.removeClass('current');
                    $prev.addClass('current');
                }

            } else {
                $next = $current.next();

                if ($next.length) {
                    flag = true;

                    /* Ako je poslednji */
                    if($current.attr('id') == "next3"){
                        $next = $current;
                    }

                    /* Ako je prvi */
                    if($current.attr('id') == "top-home"){
                        $next = jQuery("#vision-technology");
                    }


                    jQuery('body').scrollTo($next, 1000, {
                        onAfter : function(){
                            flag = false;
                        }
                    });
                    $current.removeClass('current');
                    $next.addClass('current');
                }
            }

            event.preventDefault();
        });
    });
```

Please help!!!!

Answer (score 0):

take a look of this plugin http://nick-jonas.github.io/windows/ Windows (github) is a plugin that lets you build single page websites with sections that take up the whole screens. The plugin gives you callbacks that are called when new sections come into visibility and handles snapping, so you can easily extend it with custom navigation menus or more.